# Use of dash in section numbering

Tags: style, formatting, punctuation

I am writing my thesis report and I am doubt which one is acceptable and correct?

> 1- Section 1
>  1-2- Subsection 2

Or this way?

> 1 Section 1
>  1-2 Subsection 2

Please indicate if using a dash is preferable to using a dot?

If possible, please give references.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universally correct answer to this question – this kind of formatting is usually determined by the submission regulations of the institution and department to which you are submitting the thesis.

Either check the regulations provided by the department, or take a trip to the library and ask to see examples of theses submitted in your subject area (these should be formatted according to the regulations).

If there is no regulation governing section numbering, then choose the convention most commonly used at your institution and make sure you use it consistently.

Comment: Which one is more preferred in your idea and why?

Comment: The regulations are better (they will tell you exactly what to do), but you can infer what is acceptable practice at your institution from looking at the other theses in the library if no explicit instructions are given.